# specify html form and return input in azure function c#

Tags: azure-functions

I am trying to create an Azure Function in C# that specifies a simple html form and reads the users input ehern they hit submit button.

I created a simple Azure function and added a html file to my project

My function looks like this:

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function2")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> ShowForm(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string html = await File.ReadAllTextAsync("Function2.html");
        return new ContentResult
        {
            Content = html,
            ContentType = "text/html",
            StatusCode = 200
        };
    }

    [FunctionName("Function2Submit")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string firstName = req.Form["firstName"];
        string lastName = req.Form["lastName"];

        string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstName)
            ? "Please enter your first and last name."
            : $"Hello, {firstName} {lastName}!";
        return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
    }
}
```

My html file is called `Function2.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/api/Function2" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" />
    <input type="text" name="lastName" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

When I run it from my browser it shows the htmlform on this url

```
http://localhost:7071/api/Function2
```

but when I hit submit, it returns an error http 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form is *POST*ing to Function2, but your Function2's HttpTrigger only allows a "get" method, not a POST. Didn't you mean for your form to post to Function2Submit, not to Function2?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, i did forget to specify the right function in my html form.
I changed the html from

```
<form action="/api/Function2" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```

to

```
<form action="/api/Function2Submit" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
```

Now it works fine calling an existing function.

Comment: That was my answer, correct? If my answer fixed your problem, then you should mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: Sorry your right, did not understand your anwser right away. But reading it now i Can ser it. I marked it